# How was Ross Ulbricht's IP address in San Francisco linked to Silk Road?

Tags: vpn

[Ross Ulbricht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross_Ulbricht) used a VPN server to connect to the Silk Road's server in order to configure the server.[[¹]](https://edition.cnn.com/2013/10/04/world/americas/silk-road-ross-ulbricht/index.html)

The FBI stated that Silk Road's server leaked its own IP address via a misconfigured login page, which allowed investigators to locate it in Reykjavik, Iceland,[[²]](https://www.wired.com/2014/09/the-fbi-finally-says-how-it-legally-pinpointed-silk-roads-server/). Note that Brian Krebs and others have disputed the FBI's explanation of how the server got located.[[³]](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2014/10/silk-road-lawyers-poke-holes-in-fbis-story/)

In any case, investigators found the VPN server's IP address whitelisted in the configuration of the Silk Road server.[[⁴]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43266/in-the-silkroad-takedown-what-does-it-mean-an-ip-address-was-leaking-in-tor/43280)

Somehow, the IP address Ross Ulbricht used for connecting to the VPN was found out which disclosed his location in a café on Laguna Street, San Francisco, which was close to his apartment on Hickory Street.[[⁵]](https://www.dailydot.com/unclick/fbi-investigation-dread-pirate-roberts-silk-road/)[[⁶]](https://www.sfgate.com/news/article/alleged-online-drug-kingpin-arrested-at-sf-library-4863306.php)

**Are there sources that disclose how the IP address used in the café was discovered?**

Currently, I can only reconstruct how the investigating authorities were able to determine the connection between the VPN server and Silk Road's server, but not how they identified the other half of the VPN connection: from the café to the VPN server.

Comment: Probably the investigators subpoena'd the VPN provider and demanded the IP of the client accessing Silk Road servers.

Comment: I googled: https://www.google.com/search?q=silk+road+how+the+IP+address+used+on+Laguna+Street+was+discovered%3F Top hit: https://eu.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2013/10/21/fbi-cracks-silk-road/2984921/ Which quotes "The FBI subpoenaed subscriber records from Google for the Gmail address..." Which explains the connections the FBI made. The linking of his home IP to Silk Road and the cafe was not all done via VPN IP records. I got all that in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: As linked in the question, [this article](https://www.dailydot.com/unclick/fbi-investigation-dread-pirate-roberts-silk-road/) suggests that the client IP address used in the VPN connection from the café turned up in some records: "The FBI believes that Ulbricht accessed that IP address through a Virtual Private Network (VPN) [...]. Records show that the logins originated down the street from Ulbricht’s residence."

Comment: [CNN reports](https://edition.cnn.com/2013/10/04/world/americas/silk-road-ross-ulbricht/index.html) that "the VPN server’s records indicated a user had accessed it from a San Francisco Internet café [...].". Furthermore, [this article](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/staying-anonymous-online-silk-road-founder-mistakes/) strongly indicates that the VPN server kept logs: "They used the server’s ssh config to find the VPN server Ulbricht was logging in from **and the VPN server’s last login record of IP addresses to locate a cafe near his home.**"

Comment: Think backwards. According to the narrative, they already suspected Ulbricht, but needed to make a tie. They were already gathering IPs for his personal accounts. As a result, they saw him log in to one of his accounts from the cafe. Making a leap, they could easily query for any VPN traffic from this cafe's wifi to the server they already had under surveillance. Once that was found, it's a logical assumption. They don't need to "trace back to the cafe" if they can show that the connection was made from the cafe.

Comment: And since there is debate over the FBI's details, I don't think this will be cleared up enough for you to have solid evidence that isn't refuted by someone else.